# PHP: Add Div INSIDE Echo

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I wish to add a div class ***INSIDE*** of this echo:

```
  <?php echo get_image(); ?>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. The div class must be inside (wrapper is no good). Any suggestions?

Here are some examples of what I've tried (none work):

```
 <?php echo '<div class=mydiv>' get_image();  ? '</div>'>

 <?php echo '<div class=mydiv>' .get_image();. '</div>' ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: <?php echo '<div class=mydiv>' .get_image(). '</div>' ?>  try this remove semicolon after get_image()

Comment: Make sure that `get_image()` returns a stringable result too, even though I am guessing it does in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after get_image function, also add the double quotes for classes name as echo is started with single quote.

```
<?php 
   echo '<div class="mydiv">' .get_image(). '</div>';
   echo '<div class="mydiv">' .get_image(). '</div>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing is, you can't use semi-colon(;) in the echo method, if you are using another method inside it. For that you can use this code:

**PHP**

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="your_class_name_here">' .get_image(). '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it gets more  easy, you also can also  do:

```
<?php 
echo "<DIV CLASS='yourclass'>"; get_image();
echo "</div>";    
?>
```